# Searching in a different model than the controller using Solr Sunspot in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im following Ryan's Railscast 278 for searching but I am encountering an issue.  In the example he uses, the controller and model are the exactly the same.  Both are `article`.  The code I have is a little different. What am I doing wrong here?

Different Model I am using:
**models/compact_disc.rb**

```
class CompactDisc < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title
  end
end
```

**controllers/products_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @search = CompactDisc.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end

    @compact_disc = @search.results
  end
```

**views/products/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag new_user_list_path, :method => :get do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<% for compact_disc in @compact_disc %>
    <%= image_tag "list_images/#{compact_disc.photo_url}" %>
    <%= compact_disc.title %><br/>
<% end %>
```

When I click search there are no results but the syntax is similiar to what he had in the Railscast.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is ok, but I would recommend making the search method a class method of CompactDisc:

```
class CompactDisc < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title
  end

  def self.full_text_search(query) 
    solr_search do 
        fulltext query
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can call it like

```
CompactDisc.full_text_search(params[:query])
```

Your data might not be showing up because you haven't indexed it yet. Have you made sure to do the following in the rails console?

```
CompactDisk.index
Sunspot.commit
```

Also, depending on how your schema.xml is set up, you may need to type in the exact title in order for it to match.  It's hard to debug exactly what's going on without having the data. Can you confirm that if you use the solr analyzer you can query CompacDiscs on title fine?

Comment: I'm going with the case of needing a different model so the one model/controller option won't work for me.  I did a reindex using the following command prior to running the webpage -  rake sunspot:reindex

Comment: Right, but it's cleaner to call CompactDisc.full_text_search inside the products_controller rather than creating a search function there. You can also then verify that the searching works from the rails console - it shouldn't have anything to do which which controller is calling it.